# Where can I find these definitions in algebraic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, book-recommendation, online-resources

I'm trying to understand the definitions of trigonal curve, ramification points and linear systems. What is the best place to find it? I have as background just Fulton's algebraic curves.

Thanks

Comment: Try Wikipedia , WolframAlpha or just better ... Google them!

Comment: All of this should be in Chapter IV of Hartshorne, and much of it should be accessible even to someone who hasn't read the first three chapters. Another nice source is Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris.

Comment: Actually I think I'm wrong about gonality being in Hartshorne. Anyway, trigonal just means that there is a degree $3$ map to $\mathbb P^1$. ACGH really is the one-stop shop for facts about a fixed curve.

Comment: @Hoot: right, but _which_ curve is it? </dumbjoke>